# jquery event listener for radio buttons

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a jquery event listener for a set of settings. This is a sample of the radio buttons:

```
<div class="settings">
    <input type="radio" id="a1" name="a" value="1" style="display: none;" />
        <label for="a1">a1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="a2" name="a" value="2" style="display: none;" />
        <label for="a2">a1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="a3" name="a" value="3" style="display: none;" />
        <label for="a3">a1</label>
</div>
<div class="settings">
    <input type="radio" id="b1" name="b" value="1" style="display: none;" />
        <label for="b1">a1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="b2" name="b" value="2" style="display: none;" />
        <label for="b2">a1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="b3" name="b" value="3" style="display: none;" />
        <label for="b3">a1</label>
</div>
```

I need a jquery listener for when a radio button is clicked, but I'm getting confused because the radio buttons aren't clicked, they're hidden. It's the labels that are clicked. I also need to know which button is clicked. This is far as I've gotten:

```
$('.settings label').click(function() {
    alert("Something was clicked"); // test - not working
    // need something to determine what was clicked
    updateSettings('a', 'value'); // what was checked, and the value, stored to database via separate function
});
```

But this doesn't work, and I don't know how to tell WHAT was clicked (a1, a2.. b2, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to this:

```js
$('.settings label').click(function() {
  console.log('Value of Radion: '.concat($(this).prev().val(), 'Name of radio: ', $(this).prev().attr('name')));
});
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="settings">
  <input type="radio" id="a1" name="a1" value="1" />
  <label for="a1">a1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="a2" name="a2" value="2" />
  <label for="a2">a1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="a3" name="a3" value="3" />
  <label for="a3">a1</label>
</div>
<div class="settings">
  <input type="radio" id="b1" name="b1" value="1" />
  <label for="b1">a1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="b2" name="b2" value="2" />
  <label for="b2">a1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="b3" name="b3" value="3" />
  <label for="b3">a1</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LrQk/11/)

Use Query **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('.settings label').click(function() {

          updateSettings($(this).attr('for'), $('#'+$(this).attr('for')).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put it in doc ready:

```
$(function(){
    $('.settings label').click(function() {
         var cliked = this.getAttribute('for'); // get you the for attr for clicked label
         alert(cliked + ' clicked.');
          updateSettings(cliked, $(':radio[id="'+ cliked +'"]').val()); 
          // cliked is what is clicked and other param is checked radio value
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the .change() event.

See more here: [.change() event @ jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

And see it in action here: `jsfiddle`

As shown here [how-to-use-radio-on-change-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152927/how-to-use-radio-on-change-event)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.settings label').click(function () {
    var iName = $('#'+$(this).attr('for')).attr('name');
    var iVal = $('#'+$(this).attr('for')).val()
    // need something to determine what was clicked
    updateSettings(iName,iVal); // what was checked, and the value, stored to database via separate function
});
```