# Limit the number of Input characters

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I can manipulate a control based on the state of another control, as shown in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/jy6t5oru/5/), where the state of a Checkbox alters the width and background color of a Textbox.

The HTML is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ckbxEmp" >czech Bachs
<input type="text" id="txtbxSSNOrITIN">
```

The jQuery is:

```
$(document).on("change", '[id$=ckbxEmp]', function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('[id$=txtbxSSNOrITIN]').css('background-color', '#ffff00');
        $('[id$=txtbxSSNOrITIN]').css('width', '24');
    } else {
        $('[id$=txtbxSSNOrITIN]').css('background-color', 'green');
        $('[id$=txtbxSSNOrITIN]').css('width', '144');
    }
});
```

But besides this, what I really need to do is to restrict the number of characters the user enters into the Textbox, according to whether the checkbox's state. How can I do that, preferably with CSS but, if necessary, jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jy6t5oru/11/)***

First, set `maxlength` like: `<input type="text" id="txtbxSSNOrITIN" maxlength="5">`

```
$(document).on("change", '[id$=ckbxEmp]', function () {
    
    var ckd = this.checked;                        // ckd is now a boolean 
    $('[id$=txtbxSSNOrITIN]')
        .attr("maxlength", ckd? 2 : 5)             // 2 characters if checked, else 5
        .css({
            background: ckd? '#ffff00' : "green",  // yellow if checked, else green
            width: ckd? 24 : 144                   // 24px if checked, else 144
        });
    
});
```

There's still a smaller issue above, and that's if i.e: user enters initially more than 5 characters, if you click the checkbox the value length will still be 5! So you'll need an additional strip, to remove unwanted characters like:

```
$(document).on("change", '[id$=ckbxEmp]', function () {
    
    var ckd = this.checked;
    $('[id$=txtbxSSNOrITIN]').attr("maxlength", ckd? 2 : 5).css({
       background: ckd? '#ffff00' : "green",
       width: ckd? 24 : 144
    }).val(function(i, v){
       // If checked, slice value to two characters:
       return ckd && v.length>2 ? v.slice(0,2) : v;
    });
    
});
```

If you want to *go-pro* with the code you build, you might want additionally ***improve the UX*** by storing the last (the long one) typed value. If the user clicks the checkbox and then realizes *"well... that was stupid"*, by ticking it *off* again he should get back the old value:

***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jy6t5oru/12/)***

```
$(document).on("change", '[id$=ckbxEmp]', function () {   
    
    var ckd = this.checked;
    var $input = $('[id$=txtbxSSNOrITIN]');
    if(ckd) $input.data("oldValue", $input.val() ); // Remember the current value
    
    $input.prop("maxlength", ckd? 2 : 5).css({
        background: ckd? '#ffff00' : "green",
        width: ckd? 24 : 144
    }).val(function(i, v){
        // If checked, slice value to two characters:
        return ckd && v.length>2 ? v.slice(0,2) : $input.data("oldValue");
    });
    
});
```

Comment: Awesome! You rock, Roko

Comment: For whom the code compiles: I immortalized this already-immortalized exchange here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/997548/Manipulating-Controls-Page-Elements-in-Sharepoint

Comment: @B.ClayShannon wow! thanks for the mentions. Interesting and fancifully use of English! The `$=` stuff for getting generated ID will save souls. I'm sure about that. Just, in the *Code breakdown* part I miss a SO link and some explanations what the new code does, vs. the original one. Some words on the use of `data-*` attr. to store values and on Ternary (AKA Conditional) Operator (`condition?ifTrue:else`) and the actual *need* to operate with characters (which is currently a bit obfuscated I think) would shad some light. Thx again and keep writing! You're a natural-born talent!

Comment: Most people hate my writing, as evidenced by the lack of Choctypi on my doorstep.

Comment: I updated the tip with your suggestions (added the missing link*, and some explanatory code about the "more better" version of the jQuery).
* I would make a joke about the 'missing link' but, to quote Chuck Berry, that's too much monkey business for me to be involved in.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible to do with CSS.

The jquery/javascript approach would be set a default maxlength in the input field and then change it's attribute in the checkbox event.  The numeric value can then be tied to a CSS property.

```
$('[id$=txtbxSSNOrITIN]').attr("maxlength", adjustedInputLengthVal );
```

you also have to crop the text if you're downsizing to a shorter length.

reference:
[Can I specify maxlength in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363030/can-i-specify-maxlength-in-css)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible using `CSS`. Just add the `maxlength` attribute to the input field via `jQuery`

```
$(document).on("change", '[id$=ckbxEmp]', function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('[id$=txtbxSSNOrITIN]').css('background-color', '#ffff00');
        $('[id$=txtbxSSNOrITIN]').attr('maxlength', '24');
    } else {
        $('[id$=txtbxSSNOrITIN]').css('background-color', 'green');
        $('[id$=txtbxSSNOrITIN]').attr('maxlength', '144');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You do that the same as you are doing the changes of styles:

```
$('#txtbxSSNOrITIN').attr('maxlength', '2');
```

Notice also how I replaced the selector `#txtbxSSNOrITIN`. That's a better and faster approach to select by id.

```
$('#txtbxSSNOrITIN').attr('maxlength', '10');
```

This is what happens if the checkbox isn't checked (just an example)

Don't forget to cut off the value entered by the user if the maxlength attribute gets contrained

```
$('#txtbxSSNOrITIN').val($('#txtbxSSNOrITIN').val().substr(0,2));
```

That happens in the if block. Here your fiddle modified:

http://jsfiddle.net/jy6t5oru/7/

Comment: Re your conditional text question--don't just delete questions; answer it if it's self-answered. Also the question didn't include the error you were getting, leading to a lot of comments.

Comment: I'd rather like to delete it. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind. Take my method : `maxlength`

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" />
```