# How do I have a variable on a web page that updates when needed?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have three radio buttons.  Each has a value (1, 2 or 3).  Under the radio buttons, I need a number to appear that matches the value of the radio button currently selected.  This must update in real time.

Currently I have something like this:

```
<input type="radio" Id="case" value="1" checked>
<input type="radio" Id="case" value="2">
<input type="radio" Id="case" value="3">

<script>
document.write(document.getElementById("case").value);
</script>
```

When the page is loaded, the javascript runs once, and prints "1".  I want this number to change when I select another radio button, but I'm not sure how to do that.  I'm flexible in solutions, does not have to be in javascript... any suggestions would be appreciated.  I'm using Rails.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152927/how-to-use-radio-on-change-event

Comment: do you want to active last change  if page is loaded(many time)?

Answer (score 0):

This is done by using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Consider the following code ::

```js
function changeValue(event) {
    if ( event.target.getAttribute('type') == 'radio' ) {
        document.getElementById('newValue').innerHTML = event.target.value;
    }
}

document.getElementById('buttons').addEventListener( 'click', changeValue, false );
```

```html
<div id='buttons'>
    <input type="radio" name="case" value="1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="case" value="2">
    <input type="radio" name="case" value="3">
</div>
<span id='newValue'>1</span>
```

This should help you get started writing your code that you need.

Keep in mind to give all of your inputs the same name, not the same id. The same name keeps multiple inputs from being checked at the same time. Setting the same id to multiple elements is not the standard and could cause confusion for you.

Answer (score 0):

Also one of the possible methods:

```
<input type="radio" name="case" value="1" checked />Value 1<br />
<input type="radio" name="case" value="2" />Value 2<br />
<input type="radio" name="case" value="3" />Value 3<br />
<div id="radioValue">Selected value is: <span>1</span></div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[name='case']').click(function() {
        $("div#radioValue span").text($(this).val());
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Just what I needed.  I have not used jquery before, but it looks like an excellent tool for client-side HTML manipulation.

Comment: @Ren, You must note that every single element in HTML must have unique id value. You cannot have same Id values in all Radio buttons. Validating HTML will show errors in that case.

Comment: @vivek : Didn't want to change the structure of author's original input element. However, I have changed ID => Name upon your feedback. Hopefully this or some other answer helped him fix his issues.

Answer (score -1):

Try with the given code. May be it will be the thing you need.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html >

<head>
    <title>content</title>

    
</head>

<body>

<input type="radio" Id="case" value="1" checked  name="a">
<input type="radio" Id="Radio1" value="2" name="a">
<input type="radio" Id="Radio2" value="3"  name="a">
    <span id="val"></span>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    $(function () {
        $('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
            $('#val').html($(this).val());
        })
    })

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question does not have much to do with jquery

Comment: Thanks.  I am reading into jQuery now, and it seems to be just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Jeese, Note that the question contains "I'm flexible in solutions, does not have to be in javascript". This is why I answered it as per my preference. I know that fact that is can also be done purely with JavaScript. Anyway, Thanks