# symfony form use jquery change method on input type="choice"

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony, radio-button, twig

I have radio buttons created by symfony type="choice".
when i try to do something when i choose one of them by using jquery change method nothing is happen.
the relevant part in my code:
the form:

```
$builder->add('budgetLevel', 'choice', array(
        'label'    => 'Budget level',
        'required' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => true,
        'choices'  => array('option1' => 'option1', 'option2' => 'option2', 'option3' => 'option3'),
        'widget_type'  => "inline"
    ));
 $builder->add('budgetEntity', 'text', array(
        'label'    => 'Budget Entity',
        'required' => false,

    ));
```

the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...
$("#cbg_budgetLevel").change(function(){
            alert("something");
});
... 
});
```

the html (with twig):

```
              <div id="budgetLevel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        {{ form_label(form.budgetLevel) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        {{ form_label(form.budgetEntity) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        {{ form_widget(form.budgetLevel) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        {{ form_widget(form.budgetEntity) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
```

i want that when i choose one of the options the alert will show.
why isn't its working?

Answer (score 0):

It seen that symfony convert the form field to radio-buttons.
This answer is dealing in radio-buttons well: 
[How to use radio on change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152927/how-to-use-radio-on-change-event)

anyway this is may change:
in the jquery part:

```
 $('input[type=radio][name="cbg[budgetLevel]"]').change(function(){
            if(this.value == 'option1'){
                //do option1 ...
            }
            else if(this.value == 'option2'){
                //do option2...
            }
            else{
                //do option3...
            }
        });
```