# setup a radio button when depending on which button is checked a different calculation is run?

Tags: javascript, html

Please I need  your help HTML and JavaScript how to setup a radio button when depending on which button is checked a different calculation is run?

If the Yes - 5 days is checked - then the 5 days calculation is run.
If the No - 30 days is checked - then the Yes button is closed and the 30 days calculation is run.

UPDATE:

- First - sorry for placing the codes in the comment section.  I am still learning about everything.
- Second - I have only been doing JavaScript for about 3 weeks and HTML for about 4 weeks.  I am taking courses from Lynda.com - HTML/Javascript/CSS.  These courses are good but they teach the basic and the structure but not the indepth for all the tags and the attributes.  In addition to Lynda.com, I am learning from other websites, the only thing is I am trying to learn the meaning of the tags which is not clear in some cases. 
  Thank you Sebsemillia for the suggestion on codeschool.com  I will be checking this site too.

The struggle and the challenge for me is I am doing this project (creating eForm) for work, while I am learning it.  It is not easy.

- Third - Okay - this is where I am - thank you Anthony - now the calculation for 30 days is working but not the calculation for 5 days.  Here is my https://jsfiddle.net/IS2016/751Lx395/1/ [1] - Anthony/Sebsemillia, as you could see I learned jsfiddle from both of you.  Now I could use this site, to show codes in a better format.

Not sure what I missed.

Thank you

IreneS

```
  [1] https://jsfiddle.net/IS2016/751Lx395/1/
```

UPDATE 2:

Please can someone let me know what am I missing - the 30 days calculation works but the 5 days calculation, does not work.  Even though, both of the calculations are the same setup.

Your help is very greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Irene

UPDATE 3:

FYI - I figured it out, just incase anyone following this issue and wants to know.  The reason it was not working on my side because the calculations for the 5 days and 30 days were in a separate files.  Once I put all the codes in one file, it WORKED, yeh!.  Now I need to figure out how do I leave them in a separate files and direct the function changeHandler(event)to these files.  I will figure it out, meanwhile I will leave them in one file.

I thought some of you wants to know.

Thank you to Anthony and Sebsemillia for all the help.

Irene

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use radio on change event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152927/how-to-use-radio-on-change-event)

Comment: I was able to able to complete this by using the javascript answer from the duplicate. If you have trouble solving it, set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of what you tried and I will gladly assist.

Comment: Anthony - I am still learning - I have no idea what jsfiddle is.  Also, I check the possible duplicate - but it is not straight forward for me to understand and in some cased they are using JQuery that I have no clue how it works.  I am just starting to learn javascript.

Comment: I updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you have the id `rbPubHealthYesNo` twice, so it can't work as a selector. An id should always be unique on a single page!

Here is a sample fiddle with a bit of jQuery to demonstrate how you could make it work: https://jsfiddle.net/r1hb8guu/

But there is a lot more wrong with your code, take a close look on my changes.

UPDATE:

- using inline JavaScript Handlers is considered bad practice, therefore I removed the "onclick" stuff..
- for radio buttons of the same group, they don't need identical id's but identical "name" attributes
- I took the code you posted as a comment and made it work in a new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gfznebfm/ please take a close look. There was again a lot wrong, besides from typos like 'changeEventHanler'. I wouldn't know where to start to explain things for you, you have a lot to learn and nobody in SO can teach you that. I recommend that you start learning properly about HTML, CSS, jQuery/JavaScript (in that order). There are lot of good sources out there for that. I can recommend https://www.codeschool.com/ for that, they also have free beginner courses, covering the basics of the aforementioned topics.
- next time you have a question with code, please create a working jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/). It is self explanatory how to use it. And if you want to post new code, just edit/update your question and don't write it in comments.

Comment: Sebsemillia - I am very new to all of this.  I am still trying to learn JavaScript, I am struggling to understand it all.  I have no clue about JQuery.  So I am not sure where to use the JQuery statement.   I have also noticed that you have removed the statement in the input tag calling for the JavaScript function - "onclick="javascript:USPublicHealth30Days();"  How is it going to work?

Comment: Sebsemillia - regarding the id - I am understand that id need to be unique but I thought from what I learned so far - that when using radio buttons, the id need to be the same, since when one button is checked that other can't be checked and vice versa.  That is how I understood, I could be wrong!  Thank you for your help

Comment: You can't have the same Id twice. However, you can have the same className twice. So you can change `id="rbPubHealthYesNo"` to `class="rbPubHealthYesNo"` then in your javascript change `document.getElementById('rbPubHealthYesNo')` to `getElementsByClassName('rbPubHealthYesNo')`

Comment: Anthony - I tried it per your recommendation - but it is still not working.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152927/how-to-use-radio-on-change-event) he has a javascript solution. Use the `querySelectorAll` for selecting your radio buttons. Learn more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Remove your `USPublicHealth30Days()` function and the `onclick` events from your radio buttons. Then implement the `changeHandler()` function he has. Also, use the `change` event the same as he has. [Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) to learn more about the change event.  [Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to learn more about the `forEach()` method. [Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to learn more about the `addEventListener`.

**Update**

There's a typo in your `querySelectorAll`. It should be `rbPubHealthYesNo` instead of `rbPublicHealth`. You should also remove your `onchange` events from your html, they are not needed. I also removed `document.getElementById('calc14').style.display = 'block';` and `document.getElementById('calc15').innerHTML = ''";` from your `if else` statement. In your `date30Days14()` function I changed `document.getElementById('calc15').innerHTML = text + dueDate;` to `document.getElementById('dt30Days14').value = text + dueDate;` and added `document.getElementById('dt5Days').value = "";` I did basically the same thing in your `date5Days()` function. I also removed `style="display:none"` from `<div id="USAPubHealthYesNo">`.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2k3vcwot/).

Comment: I read everything and I tried to follow as much as I am able to  understand at this time.  I have implemented the changes but still doesn't work.  What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: HTML 1st part: <div id="USAPubHealthYesNo" style="display:none">
<ol type="a" class="indentList">
<p>&nbsp;</p> <p>&nbsp;</p>
<li><input name="rbPubHealthYesNo" type="radio" class="radiobuttonfield days5" alt="Yes - five (5) day MDR report is required" title="Yes - five (5) day MDR report is required" value="Yes" onchange="changeEventHanler(event);"/>Yes - five (5) days MDR report is required 
<div id="calc14" class="indentListCalc"> 
<input id="dt5Days" type="text" class="textfieldCalc labelWidth25" />
 </div> <br> </li>

Comment: HTML 2nd part: <li><input name="rbPubHealthYesNo" type="radio" class="radiobuttonfield days30" alt="No - thirty (30) day MDR report required" title="No - thirty (30) days MDR report required" value="No" onchange="changeEventHanler(event);"/>No - thirty (30) day MDR report required
<div id="calc15" class="indentListCalc"> 
<input id="dt30Days14" type="text" class="textfieldCalc labelWidth25" />
</div><br> </li> </ol></div>

Comment: JavaScript:                                                                                            var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="rbPublicHealth"]');
function changeHandler(event) {
   if ( this.value === 'Yes' ) {
     document.getElementById('calc14').style.display = 'block';
     date5Days();
   } else if ( this.value === 'No' ) {
     document.getElementById('calc15').innerHTML = '';
     date30Days14();
   }  
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(radios, function(radio) {
   radio.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
});

Comment: Also, you shouldn't post code in the comment section. Next time edit your question with the updated code.