# How to get alert when radio button is changed in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio buttons and a text area. Now what i want to do is,when i change the radio button when text area is not empty i need a corfirm box. Only if user clicks ok Then only the radio button must be changed .or else,the value in the text area must be shown and the value of radio button must not changed..

My code

```
jQuery
--------

$(".radio1").change(function(event){

            if($(".txtarea").val() != "")
                { 
                    var flag = confirm("Do you want to change ?");
                }
            if(flag)
                {
                $(".txtarea").val("");
                }


        });


Html
------
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio1" class="radio1">hello
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio1" class="radio1">hi
<textarea id="txtarea" class="txtarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: radio1 is a id not a class

Comment: `id="radio1"` to `class="radio1"`

Comment: Change <input type="radio" id="radio1" to <input type="radio" class="radio1" also $(".txtarea").val(""); to $("#txtarea").val("");

Comment: yea its a typing mistake.. What i want to do is,If text area is not empty and user want to change the radio button to hello to hi then a confirm abox must appear. If ok, we clear the textarea and radio button is shifted to hi from hello.. When cancel, the values must not changed.I should show same as if i show them before

Comment: @Bhanu 2 html elements cannot have same id .id is unique

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152927/how-to-use-radio-on-change-event

Comment: we check the textarea value..But still the radio button is getting changed..If we click cancel both the textarea value and radio button value must not change

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=radiogroup]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'radio1') {
            alert("radio1 selected");
        }
        else if (this.value == 'radio2') {
            alert("radio2 selected");
        }
    });
});



<input type="radio" id="radio1" value="radio1" name="radiogroup" class="radio1">hello
<input type="radio" id="radio2" value="radio2" name="radiogroup" class="radio2">hi
<textarea id="txtarea" class="txtarea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example,**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=radiogroup]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'radio1') {
           
          var r = confirm("Do you want to change ?");
         if (r == true) {
           
        $("#txtarea").val("Yes!");
           } else {
         $("#txtarea").val("No!");
          }
        }
        else if (this.value == 'radio2') {
            alert("radio2 selected");
          $("#txtarea").val("");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" value="radio1" checked="checked" name="radiogroup" class="radio1">hello
<input type="radio" id="radio2" value="radio2" name="radiogroup" class="radio2">hi
<textarea id="txtarea" class="txtarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: By default one radio buton is checked.And in your code, when i change the radio button, i should get an confirm box..Not alert. When i click ok on confirm box the textarea must be cleared . But when i click on cancel, the radio button must be as it before and also text area must have the value which it has in initial state.. but i dont find my requirement in this

Answer (score 0):

as per your requirement i have created one fiddle please have a look

```
    jsfiddle.net/dhavalpankhaniya1989/4w536885/3/
```

let me know if you doubts

Comment: By default one radio buton is checked.And in your code, when i change the radio button, i should get an confirm box..Not alert. When i click ok on confirm box the textarea must be cleared . But when i click on cancel, the radio button must be as it before and also text area must have the value which it has in initail state

Comment: don't post blindly check the requirement.

Comment: please check now i have edited the link https://jsfiddle.net/dhavalpankhaniya1989/4w536885/1/

Comment: @PrabhatSinha check your solution first. is it providing proper solution ? even your solution giving alters rather then confirm

Comment: @Bhanu can you please check and let me know now ?

Comment: Its not right.. I'l update your fiddle with my requirement.. Can u give me the solution again please

Comment: have you checked [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dhavalpankhaniya1989/4w536885/3/) one ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4w536885/4/   This is my updated fiddle.. The main requirement is ,if i am clicking on cancel the text is same but the radio button value is changing..the radio button should not change..

Comment: @Dhaval i am give you suggestion only i'm not aware of that, if I'm wrong welcome your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this.

```js
$(
  function()
  {
    $(".radio1").click(function(event)
 {
   if(($(".txtarea").val()!="")&&(!$(this).attr('checked')))
   { 
        if(confirm("Do you want to change ?"))
        {
          $(".txtarea").val("");
        }
        else
        {
          return(false);
        }
      }
    });
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio1" class="radio1"/><lable for="radio1">1</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio1" class="radio1"/><lable for="radio2">2</label>
<br/>
<textarea id="txtarea" class="txtarea"></textarea>
```

NOTE - *onchange* fires after change is done, so you can't use it to prevent change

Answer (score 0):

To remove the selection from the radio, simply select another radio in the group:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name=radiogroup]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "radio2") {
      if (confirm("Are you sure?")) $("textarea").val("");
      else $("#radio1").prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

and the elements

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" value="radio1" name="radiogroup" class="radio1" checked="checked">radio1
<input type="radio" id="radio2" value="radio2" name="radiogroup" class="radio2">radio2
<textarea id="textarea" class="txtarea"></textarea>
```

try here: https://jsfiddle.net/ewnLw4wf/1/