# getElementById with Radio Button not working

Tags: javascript, html

How to get radio button value in javascript using onChange?

Here's my HTML:

```js
if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
    document.getElementById('gender2').innerHTML = "Male";
}
    
if (document.getElementById('female').checked) {
    document.getElementById('gender2').innerHTML = "Femmale";
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
    <label>
       <input type="radio" name="gender" onChange="(checkGender)" id="male" value="Male">
      Male
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" onChange="(checkGender)" id="female" value="Female">
      Female
    </label>
</div>

<td>Gender</td>
<td><span id="gender2"></span></td>
```

Comment: what does `onChange="(checkGender)" ` refer to?

Comment: Run it to see the problem - what is `checkGender`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152927/how-to-use-radio-on-change-event

Comment: (1) Wrap your JavaScript code in the `checkGender` function you're trying to refer to.  (2) This is not how you invoke a function: `(checkGender)`.  This is: `checkGender()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an actual function for call back:

```js
function checkGender() {
    if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
        document.getElementById('gender2').innerHTML = "Male";
    }
    
    if (document.getElementById('female').checked) {
        document.getElementById('gender2').innerHTML = "Femmale";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
    <label>
       <input type="radio" name="gender" onChange="checkGender()" id="male" value="Male">
      Male
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" onChange="checkGender()" id="female" value="Female">
      Female
    </label>
</div>

<td>Gender</td>
<td><span id="gender2"></span></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is executed once, when the page loads. You need to call it when something changes (based on an event), and react to the change.

HTML:

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" onclick="checkGender()" id="male" value="Male">
        Male
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" onclick="checkGender()" id="female" value="Female">
        Female
    </label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function checkGender() {
    if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
        document.getElementById('gender2').innerHTML = "Male";
    }

    if (document.getElementById('female').checked) {
        document.getElementById('gender2').innerHTML = "Femmale";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an event handler to the container (`.radio`) using [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). When the handler is triggered check if the event target is a radio button using [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches). If is is and radio button update the value of the `#gender1` div:

```js
var radio = document.querySelector('.radio');
var gender2 = document.getElementById('gender2');

radio.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if(!e.target.matches('input[type=radio]')) return;
  
  gender2.innerText = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<div class="radio">
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">
        Male
    </label>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">
        Female
    </label>
</div>

<div id="gender2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener on radio buttons and check for the values.

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');

var genderEl = document.getElementById("gender");

for(var i=0; i< radios.length; i++)
{
     radios[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       genderEl.innerHTML = this.value
     
     })

}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender"   id="male" value="Male">
        Male
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender"   id="female" value="Female">
        Female
    </label>
    
    <h3 id="gender"></h3>
</div>
```

Note: You should always use `eventlisteners` rather than using inline event handlers. Inline event handlers are evaluated as `eval`. Moreover, it's a bad practice