# How to undo a javascript command after unchecking the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, if-statement

I am trying to write a program that calculates the price of being at the garage, but I don't know how to cancel the function after I unchecking the checkbox. here's my code:

```js
function Car() {
  var value = 0;
  var PrivateCar = document.getElementById("PrivateCar").value;
  var CommercialCar = document.getElementById("CommercialCar").value;
  var Truck = document.getElementById("Truck").value;
  var ScentTree = document.getElementById("ScentTree").value;
  var PrivateCarWax = document.getElementById("PrivateCarWax").value;
  var CommercialCarWax = document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").value;
  if (document.form1.PrivateCar.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("Car").innerHTML = "You have a private car." + "<br />";
    value += 30;
  }
  if (document.form1.CommercialCar.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("Car").innerHTML = "You have a commercial car" + "<br />";
    value += 45;
  }
  if (document.form1.Truck.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("Car").innerHTML = "You have a truck" + "<br />";
    value += 60;
  }
  if (document.form1.ScentTree.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("Extras").innerHTML = "You have chosen the addition of a scent tree" + "<br />";
    value += 5;
  }
  if (document.form1.PrivateCarWax.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("Extras").innerHTML = "You have chosen the addition of Wax to a private car" + "<br />";
    value += 10;
  }
  if (document.form1.CommercialCarWax.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("Extras").innerHTML = "You have chosen the addition of Wax to a private car" + "<br />";
    value += 20;
  }
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "The price you have to pay is: " + value + " dollars";
}
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">
  <form name="form1">
    <h1 style="color:red">Car Washing Price List</h1>
    <br />
    <b>Car Type:</b>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="PrivateCar" name="CarType" /> Private Car - 30 dollars
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="CommercialCar" name="CarType" /> Commercial Car - 45 dollars
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="Truck" name="CarType" /> Truck - 60 dollars
    <br />
    <br />
    <b>Extras:</b>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="ScentTree" /> Scent tree - 5 dollars
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="PrivateCarWax" /> Wax for private car - 10 dollars
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="CommercialCarWax" /> Wax for commercial car - 20 dollars
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="TruckWax" disabled /> Wax for truck - You can't choose wax for a truck
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Click to get a price" onclick="Car()" />
    <p id="Car"></p>
    <p id="Extras"></p>
    <p id="price"></p>
  </form>
```

I am trying to:

1. Disable the "CommercialCarWax" checkbox after clicking "PrivateCar" radio button.
2. Disable the "PrivateCarWax" checkbox after clicking "CommercialCar" radio button.
3. Disable the "CommercialCarWax" checkbox and the "PrivateCarWax" checkbox after clicking "Truck" radio button.

Comment: There is a syntax error somewhere in your code

Comment: The `<script>...</script>` tags do not belong in the JavaScript box.

Comment: Just run the `Car` method on change of the radio buttons.... Also `Car` would indicated a class/constructors, not a function. Casing has meaning.

Comment: You're looking for [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener). Basically you set up a `change` event listener on the radio buttons, and then trigger a function to enable/disable checkboxes based on the new radio value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use radio on change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152927/how-to-use-radio-on-change-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your condition while handling radio button changes event. Just play around your condition here.

```
    var radioBtn = document.form1.CarType
for (var i = 0; i < radioBtn.length; i++) {
    radioBtn[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        if(this.id == "PrivateCar") { disabledBox(false,true) }
else if(this.id == "CommercialCar") { disabledBox(true,false) }
    else if(this.id == "Truck") { disabledBox(true,true) }    
    });
}
function disabledBox(val1, val2) { 
document.getElementById("PrivateCarWax").disabled = val1;
document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").disabled = val2;
}
```

Here is the approach to do your requirement:

```js
function Car() {
  var value = 0;
  var PrivateCar = document.getElementById("PrivateCar").value;
  var CommercialCar = document.getElementById("CommercialCar").value;
  var Truck = document.getElementById("Truck").value;
  var ScentTree = document.getElementById("ScentTree").value;
  var PrivateCarWax = document.getElementById("PrivateCarWax").value;
  var CommercialCarWax = document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").value;



  if (document.form1.PrivateCar.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("Car").innerHTML = "You have a private car." + "<br />";
    value += 30;
  }
  if (document.form1.CommercialCar.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("Car").innerHTML = "You have a commercial car" + "<br />";
    value += 45;
  }
  if (document.form1.Truck.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("Car").innerHTML = "You have a truck" + "<br />";
    value += 60;
  }
  if (document.form1.ScentTree.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("Extras").innerHTML = "You have chosen the addition of a scent tree" + "<br />";
    value += 5;
  }
  if (document.form1.PrivateCarWax.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("Extras").innerHTML = "You have chosen the addition of Wax to a private car" + "<br />";
    value += 10;
  }
  if (document.form1.CommercialCarWax.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("Extras").innerHTML = "You have chosen the addition of Wax to a private car" + "<br />";
    value += 20;
  }
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "The price you have to pay is: " + value + " dollars";
}
var radioBtn = document.form1.CarType
for (var i = 0; i < radioBtn.length; i++) {
    radioBtn[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        if(this.id == "PrivateCar") { disabledBox(false,true) }
else if(this.id == "CommercialCar") { disabledBox(true,false) }
    else if(this.id == "Truck") { disabledBox(true,true) }    
    });
}
function disabledBox(val1, val2) { 
document.getElementById("PrivateCarWax").disabled = val1;
document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").disabled = val2;
}
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">
  <form name="form1">
    <h1 style="color:red">Car Washing Price List</h1>
    <br />
    <b>Car Type:</b>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="PrivateCar" name="CarType" /> Private Car - 30 dollars
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="CommercialCar" name="CarType" /> Commercial Car - 45 dollars
    <br />
    <input type="radio" id="Truck" name="CarType" /> Truck - 60 dollars
    <br />
    <br />
    <b>Extras:</b>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="ScentTree" /> Scent tree - 5 dollars
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="PrivateCarWax" /> Wax for private car - 10 dollars
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="CommercialCarWax" /> Wax for commercial car - 20 dollars
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="TruckWax" disabled /> Wax for truck - You can't choose wax for a truck
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Click to get a price" onclick="Car()" />
    <p id="Car"></p>
    <p id="Extras"></p>
    <p id="price"></p>
  </form>
```

Comment: For some reason, I see that it's good when I run from Stack Overflow, but when I run it from Visual Studio the code does not work. I don't think it's related to Visual Studio but it's very strange...

Comment: what issue do you get while running in VS? I tried this as a simple html form as well. its working. In your case, it might be your code that cause the problem?

Comment: I don't get any issue, it's just doesn't working when I try to run it.

Comment: Can you confirm if whole page has unique id? this might be the reason it doesn't work. In console, write query like `document.querySelectorAll('yourradiobutton/classname')`.

Comment: It opens the site but if I choose "PrivateCar" for example it allows me to choose "CommercialCarwax" and vice versa.

Comment: Yes then you might have issue of duplicate id in the page. can you check if you unique id of all those radio and checkbox?

Comment: Yes, I have unique id for every single radio button and checkbox

Comment: can you put a debugger in disbledBox and check wether it is picking up a right checkbox and add a disable attribute?

Comment: Do you mean that I need just to give the same name for all the radio buttons and the checkboxes?

Comment: Same name for all radio button is necessary. no needed name of checkboxes. only Unique id required for all radio and checkbox. what I am suggesting you to check is: put a `debugger;` in `disabledBox()` and check if it adds a disable attribute to checkbox or not

Comment: instead of ```disabledBox(true, false)``` put a ```disabledBox(decugger;)``` ?

Comment: or like this: ```debugger(disabledBox(true, false));```?

Comment: function disabledBox(val1, val2) { 
document.getElementById("PrivateCarWax").disabled = val1;
document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").disabled = val2;
debugger;
}
reload the page and check in console. you will see your broswer pause when you select the radio button. here you check if it is working on correct checkbox

Comment: The browser didn't pause... It didn't do anything.

Comment: I tried to do this: 
```function DisableCommercialCarWax() {
            document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").disabled == true;
        }```
and then this:
```<input type="radio" id="PrivateCar" name="CarType" onclick="DisableCommercialCarWax()"/>```
Maybe it's good?

Comment: document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").disabled == true;  should be document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").disabled = true;. the way I created was generic way, you can add and remove easily in it. The approach you are following is also ok. It will work

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!
But now if I choose for example CommercialCar and then PrivateCar I can't choose PrivateCarWax.
How to change it?

Comment: You need to set it disabled = false when you click on other radio button

Comment: Also, just want to check : can you confirm your form name is `form1` and radiobutton name is 'CarType'?

Comment: If above code is working, I believe you don't have form name / radio button name same as you mentioned in the question. so you can check that and the approach I provided will solve your all issues.

Comment: Yes, my form name is ```form1```and the radio buttons is ```CarType```

Comment: then last thing which comes in my mind is, it doesn't bind change event on radio button. that means you need to write this code where it can be reachable on event change might be in document.ready function() ?

Comment: Should it be like that:

Comment: if (document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").disabled = true && document.getElementById("PrivateCar").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").disabled = false;
        }

Comment: if (document.getElementById("PrivateCarWax").disabled = true && document.getElementById("CommercialCar").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("PrivateCarWax").disabled = false;
        }

Comment: if (document.getElementById("PrivateCarWax").disabled = true && document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").disabled == true && document.getElementById("PrivateCar").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("PrivateCarWax").disabled = false;
        }

Comment: honestly saying, this approach is not good. but to make it work you have wrong condition,
if(document.getElementById("PrivateCarWax").disabled = true should be 
document.getElementById("PrivateCarWax").disabled == true in every scenario. many things to correct. hold on!

Comment: doesn't matter, I already found a way to do it, thanks for all the support!!!

Comment: I did it in a function and also put it in the ```onclick``` of every radio button, like this (for example):
```function EnablePrivateCar() {
            document.getElementById("PrivateCarWax").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("CommercialCarWax").checked = false;
        }```
and then in the radio button:
```<input type="radio" id="PrivateCar" name="CarType" onclick="DisableCommercialCarWax() + EnablePrivateCar()"/>```

Comment: There is a problem with your code: when I click on the Truck it doesn't turn off the other checkboxes. Anyway I already found another way, I wrote it in the last message ↑

Comment: I haven't written all the condition. you probably require to add that just like other condition I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Well, where to start?

It is generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers.

Furthermore, if you add [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to your input elements for the price, it's easier to calculate the total price.

It's way easier to use [css-selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to query the DOM-elements

Finally, you can add one event listener to the document to handle different events. This is called [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

With the previous in mind, I've rewritten your snippet (edited the html and shortened it a bit too). Bonus: it will calculate the price every time some choice is made.

You should be able to figure out how to conditionally disable radiobuttons or checkboxes (hint: `setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')`).

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "button" || 
      evt.target.type === "radio" || 
      evt.target.type === "checkbox") {
  // Note: the calculation will also be triggered if 
  // one of the radio buttons or checkboxes is clicked
  // so you may consider ditching the button
    getPrice(evt.target);
  }
}

function getPrice(origin) {
  let checkedRadio;
  
  if (origin.type === "radio") {
    checkedRadio = origin;
  } else {
    checkedRadio = document.querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked");
  }
  
  const checkedCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");

  if (!checkedRadio) {
    return alert("Please select a Car Type");
  }
  
  let total = +checkedRadio.dataset.price;
  checkedCheckboxes
    .forEach(cb => total += +cb.dataset.price);
  document.querySelector("#price").textContent = `Your price: $${total}`;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <h1 style="color:red">Car Washing Price List</h1>
  <div>
    <h3>Car Type:</h3>
    <input type="radio" id="PrivateCar" name="CarType" data-price="30" /> Private Car - 30 dollars
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="CommercialCar" name="CarType" data-price="45" /> Commercial Car - 45 dollars
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Extras:</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ScentTree" data-price="5" /> Scent tree - 5 dollars
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="PrivateCarWax" data-price="10" /> Wax for private car - 10 dollars
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="CommercialCarWax" data-price="20" /> Wax for commercial car - 20 dollars
    </div>
    <p>
      <input type="button" id="button" value="Click to get a price" /> <span id="price"></span>
    </p>  
</form>
```